# Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace error when trying to render

Tags: reactjs

here is the map function I'm trying to pass while rendering content to the html but i'm getting `, expected` error on line 3 in the conditional operator. And also on the closing bracket I'm getting `Unexpected token. Did you mean` {'}'}`or`}    why can that be? Is it due to syntax?

```
 {newMessages.map(function (item) {
                         return (
                          { userId === item.event.sender ?
                            <div class="flex justify-start mb-4">
                              <div
                                class="ml-2 py-3 px-4 bg-blue-400 rounded-br-3xl rounded-tr-3xl rounded-tl-xl text-white"
                              >
                                {item.event.content.body}
                              </div>
                              <img
                                src="https://source.unsplash.com/vpOeXr5wmR4/600x600"
                                class="object-cover h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                                alt=""
                              />
                            </div>
                            :
                            <div class="flex justify-end mb-4">
                              <img
                                src="https://source.unsplash.com/vpOeXr5wmR4/600x600"
                                class="object-cover h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                                alt=""
                              />
                              <div
                                class="ml-2 py-3 px-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-br-3xl rounded-tr-3xl rounded-tl-xl text-white"
                              >
                                {item.event.content.body}
                              </div>
                            </div>}                     
                            )
                      }
                    )
                    }
```

Comment: You have extra `{...}` here `return { userId === item.event.sender ? ... : ...}`. It should be `return userId === item.event.sender ? ... : ... `

Answer (score 0):

`{` should be used in when interpolating a JavaScript expression into JSX - for example `<div>{someVariable}</div>`. If you're not in the context of JSX, using `{` instead delimits the beginning of an object literal.

Since you're not in JSX context at this point:

```
return (
    { userId === item.event.sender ?
    ^
```

An error is thrown.

Here, you can remove the `{` entirely and return the array of elements, without any JSX at that level.

```
{newMessages.map(function (item) {
  return (
    userId === item.event.sender ?
```

The time you'd want to use `{` there would be if there was something element surrounding each mapped item, eg:

```
{newMessages.map(function (item) {
  return (
    <div className="item-container">
      {
        userId === item.event.sender ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work

```
{
    newMessages.map(function (item) {
        return userId === item.event.sender ? (
            <div className="flex justify-start mb-4">
                <div className="ml-2 py-3 px-4 bg-blue-400 rounded-br-3xl rounded-tr-3xl rounded-tl-xl text-white">
                    {item.event.content.body}
                </div>
                <img
                    src="https://source.unsplash.com/vpOeXr5wmR4/600x600"
                    className="object-cover h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                    alt=""
                />
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div className="flex justify-end mb-4">
                <img
                    src="https://source.unsplash.com/vpOeXr5wmR4/600x600"
                    className="object-cover h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                    alt=""
                />
                <div className="ml-2 py-3 px-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-br-3xl rounded-tr-3xl rounded-tl-xl text-white">
                    {item.event.content.body}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```

You were using extra curly braces

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors. Just make sure you enclose each JSX block with parentheses `()` and to use `className` property instead of `class` since it is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

```
{newMessages.map((item) =>
  userId === item.event.sender ? (
    <div className="flex justify-start mb-4">
      <div className="ml-2 py-3 px-4 bg-blue-400 rounded-br-3xl rounded-tr-3xl rounded-tl-xl text-white">
        {item.event.content.body}
      </div>
      <img
        src="https://source.unsplash.com/vpOeXr5wmR4/600x600"
        className="object-cover h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="flex justify-end mb-4">
      <img
        src="https://source.unsplash.com/vpOeXr5wmR4/600x600"
        className="object-cover h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
        alt=""
      />
      <div className="ml-2 py-3 px-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-br-3xl rounded-tr-3xl rounded-tl-xl text-white">
        {item.event.content.body}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
)}
```